# Why do we send the lengths of strings as parameters to functions when we can use strlen() inside the function to get the lengths of the words?

Tags: c, string, function, parameters, arguments

I have been thinking about this question for a while and today I came across a tutorial and decided to ask away.

A lot of tutorials on the internet get the lengths of the strings using strlen() inside main function and send it to functions as arguments. Why don't we simply pass the strings into functions and use strlen() inside functions?

Example:

Why do people use this:

```
int function (const char * word1, int len1, const char * word2, int len2){
    ...
}

int main (){
    distance (word1, strlen(word1), word2, strlen(word2));
}
```

instead of this:

```
int function (char * word1, char * word2){
    ...
    int len1 = strlen(word1);
    int len2 = strlen(word2);
    ...
}

int main (){
    distance (word1, word2);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing the length

1. saves CPU time (`strlen` is an `O(n)` function—measuring the string takes time)
2. allows you to pass a substring or deal with a character array that's not null-terminated.

Some functions take your approach and measure their input strings' length themselves. It's a trade-off between runtime efficiency and a small API convenience.

Comment: If it is not null-terminated, it is not a string; the null-terminator is _part_ of the string itself.

Comment: suggest "... deal with a character array that's not null character terminated."